# Schema Migration without data loss

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find a software or looking on a way to generate schema migration scripts from one environment to another, Dev -> Test -> Live without losing existing data on each environment.

We have 3 standard servers that we use for developing new features, and i am trying to automate the process of migrating new tables or new columns without affecting existing data.

Is there any built in feature in MSSQL for this or is there any open source software that can handle this?

I looked over RedGate software but their prices are rather high and forcing a big package that i don't really need. i'm interested in something to strictly help me migrate schema changes, and if it could be implemented within Jenkins then it's even better.

Comment: You should use tools like http://liquibase.org/ or  https://flywaydb.org/ to manage your schema migration. Then you wouldn't need a tool that compares environments (which isn't going to work reliably to begin with)

Comment: DacFx is SQL Server's own technology for schema comparison/migration.